# Can Blender draw curves in 2D mode like Sai does?

Tags: animation, 2d

Can I manually place vertices\control points as I go instead of slapping a poopy curve and then editing it with wiggle handles? Maybe I'm missing something or there's an add-on?

[image]

I'm talking about this layout\mode

[image]

Comment: Sai may be this https://painttool-sai.en.softonic.com/? This question really needs a clearer explanation of what it is trying to ask

Comment: @NeverConvex Yes indeed. It looks as if the question may be about grease pencil in Blender in that case, in which case I can't help as I've never used it.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about 2D-animation mode, aka Grease pencil I guess. SAI is a painting software. I'm asking if there's a way to make curves in the same way as on a gif, drawing it point by point, in Blender I only see tools that plop a curve or polyline that you have to go to edit mode to shape, it's not very convenient :/ Idk how I can make it clearer than showing a recording of what I need lol

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Bezier Utilities Addon](https://github.com/Shriinivas/blenderbezierutils) by [Shriinivas Kulkami](https://github.com/Shriinivas) to get illustration software like bezier curve creation and editing tools.

It adds two tools to the 3D View toolbar *Flexy Draw Bezier* and *Flexy Edit Bezier*, which allow you to both draw and edit existing bezier curve objects respectively.
[image]

It behaves similar to vector editing software like Inkscape, allowing you to draw bezier curve objects by clicking the viewport and dragging to draw straight or curved segments.

[image]

Editing works directly from object mode, by dragging segments points and handles.

[image]

Comment: That's kind of what polyline tool already does

Comment: Yes indeed. In fact those icons are for the built-in Bezier Utilities addon!